# Can not use keyboard 3rd level on Manjaro

Tags: keyboard, manjaro, xfce

I feel all my settings right:

```
~/: setxkbmap -print -verbose 10

Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,ru
variant:    ,
options:    grp:shift_caps_switch,lv3:switch,nbsp:level2
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us+ru:2+inet(evdev)+group(shift_caps_switch)+level3(switch)+nbsp(level2)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+ru:2+inet(evdev)+group(shift_caps_switch)+level3(switch)+nbsp(level2)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};

~/: localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: us,ru
       X11 Model: pc105
     X11 Variant: ,
     X11 Options: grp:shift_caps_switch,lv3:ralt_switch_multikey,numpad:mac,nbsp:level2
```

But the 3rd level or compose layer (ralt+shift) just does nothing. And it seems to me like there is no of these layouts in my Manjaro (XFCE) distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've found the reason: need to add typo layout to every layout in xkb:

`$ setxkbmap -layout us+typo,ru:2+typo`

Also, 3rd level should be enabled, for example like:

`lv3:ralt_switch_multikey`

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for sharing your solution. I was wondering why you would need typo and lv3? Also how do you use the lv3 tag? Is is like `$ setxkbmap -layout us+lv3:ralt_switch_multikey`?

Comment: Ok nvm I found out how to use the lv3 option but Im still not sure what typo is for

Comment: typo layout has some unicode symbols for everyday use: — ± €₽×⋅¹²³⅓½¼ © etc